# Get the string values of attributes in XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath, attributes

How can I get the values of an attribute node with XPath?
Example XML file:

```
<model:testFile name="$test1$">
  <model:task exec="/" />
</model:testFile>
<model:testFile name="$test2$">
  <model:task exec="/" />
</model:testFile>
```

I need to get the string values for the attribute name.

If I use: `string(//model:testFile/@name)`, I get `$test1$` as an output.

This is how I would like the output for the example above to look like:

```
$test1$
$test2$
```

Comment: It depends on the xpath client you use. Are you talking about a script or program?
Because you state that you already got the first correct result and just need some kind of loop to get the next one.
For example with Java you need to evaluate your statement like expr.evaluate(doc) where expr is your xpath expression and doc obviously the xml document.
And then you get a NodeList over which you can iterate.

Answer (score 2):

The `string()` function returns a single string. In XPath 1.0, if you apply it to a sequence of >1 node, it gives you the string value of the first node. In 2.0+ it gives you an error.

In XPath 1.0 there is no such data type as "a sequence of strings", so you cannot return a sequence of strings from your expression however hard you try. What you can do is return a sequence of nodes, and have the host application extract the string values of the nodes.

In XPath 2.0 you can return a sequence of strings: use `//model:testFile/@name/string()`. Or you can join the strings into a single string with a newline separator using `string-join(//model:testFile/@name, '&#xa;')`. (I've used XML escaping for the newline here; if the XPath is hosted in a language that represents newline as `\n`, then use that instead.)

Please always say which XPath version you are using - it makes it much easier to answer questions helpfully.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which xpath processor you are using, but try this:

```
string-join(//model:testFile/@name,' ')
```